# multiple file streaming hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have two matrices on separate files .  I have to read the files into cache so that I can multiply them. I have been wondering if HDFS would help me. I am suspecting that HDFS does not because it does not have enough cache memory to read the files and processes it . in short can i open two files at the same time

Answer (score 0):

To answer your shorter version of the question, yes the HDFS API does allow concurrent reads of two files at a time. You may simply create two input streams over the two files and read them in parallel (as you would with regular files) and manage your logic around that.

However, the HDFS is a simple FileSystem and has no cache of its own to offer (other than the OS buffer cache) and any cache for computation you need to carry, needs to be taken care of by your own application.

As another general recommendation, since you look to be multiplying matrices, perhaps look at the [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) and [Apache Hama](http://hama.apache.org) projects that support HDFS.